# how to add dynamically row values in bootstrap table using angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

> I am Using angular 4 bootstrap table :When i enter one product
>   in text box while i click enter button i am getting first row value in
>   a table from  backend,but again i enter another one product in text box
>   2nd row values is not display in table,i given alert window its
>   showing 2nd row values also...how to add second row  or multiple row values in
>   a table???

**alert:**
In my alert window showing data----[[2,"second",1,1,2,1,1,10.2,1]]

**ang.html:**

```
<div class="col-lg-4">                                           
         <label class="col-form-label labal">Product Name</label> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control inputline" placeholder="Search Product Name" name="brand" id="brand" list="brandlist" (change)="getBrandlist($event)"> 
    <datalist id="brandlist" name="brandlist" (change)="getBrandlist($event)">                                                    </datalist>  </div> 
            <table>
                  <thead>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Product Id</th> 
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Formulation</th> </thead>
           <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let brand of brandlist; let i = index">               
                    <td>{{ i + 1}} </td>
                    <td>{{brand[i][0]}}</td>
                    <td>{{brand[i][1]}}</td>
                    <td>{{brand[i][2]}}</td>      
                   </tr>                    
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

**component.ts:**

```
brandlist=[];
    getBrandlist($event)
      {
          let val=$event.target.value     
          this.invoiceService.getBrandlist(val).subscribe(data => {this.getTabledata(data)},
            error=>
            {
               console.log('Error occured On getBrandlist');
            });     
      }
      getTabledata(data)
      {
        if(data!==undefined || data!==null)
        {
          alert(JSON.stringify(data));
          this.brandlist.push(data);     
        }
      }
```

Comment: brand[i][0] don't use [i] brand equals to brandlist[i]

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming the data in side the brandlist is

```
[[1,"first",1,1,2,1,1,10.2,1],


[[2,"second",1,1,2,1,1,10.2,1]]]
```

it worked for the first array 
since

```
row 1 brand[0][0]=which is 1
```

for `row 2 brand[1][0]=which is [2,"second",1,1,2,1,1,10.2,1]`

just try to `alert(JSON.stringify(brandlist));`
or `cosole.log(brandlist);`
after adding second item/row